# Haskell - guard inside case statement

Tags: haskell, pattern-guards

I am going through [Learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) book, and in Chapter 8 there is a snippet of code which looks like this

```
data LockerState = Taken | Free deriving (Eq, Show)
type Code = String
type LockerMap = Map.Map Int (LockerState, Code)

lookup' :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code
lookup' num_ map_ =
   case (Map.lookup num_ map_) of
      Nothing -> Left $ "LockerNumber doesn't exist!"
      Just (state, code) -> if state == Taken
                              then Left $ "LockerNumber already taken!"
                              else Right $ code
```

This works. However, I wanted to convert if/else block to guard statements like this:

```
lookup' :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code
lookup' num_ map_ =
   case (Map.lookup num_ map_) of
      Nothing -> Left $ "LockerNumber doesn't exist!"
      Just (state, code) ->
         | state == Taken = Left $ "LockerNumber already taken!"
         | otherwise = Right $ Code
```

This doesn't compile. It seems that usage of guards in Haskell is very restrictive/non intuitive. [SO Ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124558/is-it-possible-to-nest-guards-in-haskell/34124909#34124909) [SO Ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327374/haskell-defining-a-function-with-guards-inside-a-where). Is there a definite source which I can read which tells at which places I can use guards?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are two places guards are allowed: function definitions and `case` expressions. In both contexts, guards appear *after* a pattern and *before* the body, so you use `=` in functions and `->` in `case` branches, as usual:

```
divide x y
  | y == 0 = Nothing
  --------
  | otherwise = Just (x / y)
  -----------

positively mx = case mx of
  Just x | x > 0 -> Just x
         -------
  _ -> Nothing
```

Guards are simply *constraints* for patterns, so `Just x` matches any non-`Nothing` value, but `Just x | x > 0` only matches a `Just` whose wrapped value is also positive.

I suppose the definitive reference is the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/), specifically §3.13 Case Expressions and §4.4.3 Function and Pattern Bindings, which describe the syntax of guards and specify where they’re allowed.

In your code, you want:

```
Just (state, code)
  | state == Taken -> Left "LockerNumber already taken!"
  | otherwise -> Right code
```

This is also expressible with patterns alone:

```
Just (Taken, _) -> Left "LockerNumber already taken!"
Just (_, code) -> Right code
```

Comment: Great answer! especially the line `Guards are simply constraints for patterns`