# How do I use "<0" condition in Haskell case

Tags: haskell, syntax, conditional-statements

So i am trying to make a recursive factorial function using the `case` expression and `if else` although I don't know how to write the `<0` condition for my code

```
factorial x = case of x
                      <0 -> -1
                       0 ->  0
                          .
                          .
                          .
```

I am completely new to Haskell so please don't be too harsh on me.

Comment: In a `case` you use a pattern rather than a condition. Maybe try `if x < 0` instead?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. editor tells me there is a parse error on first '->'

Comment: @m3k_1: it is `case x of`, not `case of x`, but you can not work with a condition directly, you will need guards, or pattern matching (view patterns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` takes an arbitrary expression, not just a single variable, so you could write something like

```
factorial x = case compare x 0 of
               LT -> -1
               EQ -> 1
               GT -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a guard, for example:

```
factorial x
  | x < 0 = -1
factorial 0 = 0
-- ⋮
```

or we can add these guards to the case statement, as [@Dan D. says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516054/how-do-i-use-0-condition-in-haskell-case/67516157?noredirect=1#comment119336875_67516157):

```
factorial x = case x of
  x | x < 0 -> -1
  0 -> 0
-- ⋮
```

or you can work with [*view patterns* [Haskell gitlab wiki]](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/view-patterns):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

factorial x = case x of
  ((< 0) -> True) -> -1
  0 -> 1
  -- ⋮
```

Comment: Are not guards supported in case expressions as https://stackoverflow.com/a/40836465 shows?

Comment: @DanD.: yes indeed. Somehow I find it a bit ugly however since we use the `x` variable *four* times: one in the head of the function definition, one in the `case ... of`, one in the pattern, and one in the guard.

Comment: pretty intricate way to write `case (x < 0) of True -> ...` or just `if (x < 0) then ....`. :)